# httpclient.execute in httppost method is not working with emulator when using AsyncTask implementation

Tags: android-asynctask, android-emulator

I am new to android and was trying an async task implementation for fetching some data from webservices APIs and it works fine with normal single thread (UI main) implementations. But on  moving to AsyncTask for proper  implementation and better UX, I am not able to trigger a network message. Could anyone please help me in finding out  what could be going wrong here, I am attaching my code snippet here,

```
private class HttpConnector extends AsyncTask<String,String ,String> 
{
    private final String Name;
    private final String setID; 
    private final String setCntrlValue;
    private final String effDate;

    HttpConnector(String aName,String aSetId, String aDate)
    {
        Name=aName;
        setID=aSetId;
        effDate=aDate;

    }


  String response="";
  protected String doInBackground(String ... params) 
    {
        response="";
        String soapCall="<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" ";
        soapCall+=" xmlns:get=\"http://XXXX/GET_TREE_REQUEST.v1\">";
        soapCall+="<soapenv:Header/>";
        soapCall+="<soapenv:Body>";
        soapCall+="<get:TreeData>";
        soapCall+="<get:TreeName>"+Name.toString()+"</get:TreeName>";
        soapCall+="<get:SETID>"+setID.toString()+"</get:SETID>";
        soapCall+="<get:EFFDT>"+effDate.toString()+"</get:EFFDT>";
        soapCall+="</get:TreeData>";
        soapCall+="</soapenv:Body>";
        soapCall+="</soapenv:Envelope>";

        System.setProperty("socksProxyHost", "XXXX");
        System.setProperty("socksProxyPort", "XX");

         HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
          // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
         int timeoutConnection = 15000;
         HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
          // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT)
          // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
         int timeoutSocket = 0;
         HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

         org.apache.http.client.HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

         HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);
         httppost.setHeader("soapaction", "XXXX.v1");
         httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");

         try{

              HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity(soapCall.toString(),HTTP.UTF_8);
              httppost.setEntity(entity);
              HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);// calling server
              InputStream content = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

              BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
              String s = "";
              while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                response += s;
              }
             return response;
        }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
             return e.getStackTrace().toString();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
             return e.getStackTrace().toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
             return e.getStackTrace().toString();
       }catch (Exception e) 
        {   
            return e.getStackTrace().toString();
        }finally{
             httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();//shut down the connection
        }
    }
    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
         //super.onPostExecute(response);
         txtResponse.setText(response);
   } 


}

  public class FirstAppUI extends Activity 
  {
     public void onClick(View v)
     {
        HttpConnector netConnect= new           HttpConnector(txtTreeName.getText().toString(),txtSetId.getText().toString(),txtEffDate.getText().toString()); 
        netConnect.execute(); 
        txtResponse.setText("Waiting for the Server Response..!!"); 

      }
 }
```

And I am trigerring the AsynTask as above from my activity class. And the code flow stops at httpclient.execute(httppost) line.

Thanks